# Ionic Native Google Maps plugin - set app background color

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I'm having trouble with Ionic 3, specifically setting the app background color when using the native Google Maps plugin. The map is a native element "under" the browser, and having background color set for the Ionic app covers the map and prevents it from showing.

[When looking at the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/#Environment), there is a `setBackgroundColor(color)` method in the `Environment` class, but I have no idea where I'm supposed to use that class. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I simply instantiated the `Environment` class and then called `setBackgroundColor`. Like this:

```
import { Environment } from '@ionic-native/google-maps`;

export class MyClass {

  environment: Environment = null;

  myMethod(): void {
    this.environment = new Environment();
    this.environment.setBackgroundColor("red");
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to set a linear-gradient as a background color?¿

Answer (score 0):

Wow. It's kind of surprised for me. @mkkekkonen's answer worked certainly, but it is not my intended design way.
(I'm the author of cordova-plugin-googlemaps, and main maintainer of `@ionic-native/google-maps` plugin).

The Environment, Geocoder, Spherical, Poly(oh, not implemented yet), and Encoding classes are **static class** in original plugin.

For example, I think nobody do like this, but it is possible.
This is not my intended way.

```
import { Environment } from '@ionic-native/google-maps`;

export class MyClass {

  environment: Environment = null;

  myMethod1(): void {
    (new Environment()).setBackgroundColor("red");
  }
  myMethod2(): void {
    (new Environment()).setBackgroundColor("blue");
  }
}
```

---

The correct way is to use `provider` (@4.3.3)

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-set-background-color',
  templateUrl: 'set-background-color.html',
  providers: [
    Environment
  ]
})
export class SetBackgroundColorPage {

  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(
      public navCtrl: NavController,
      public navParams: NavParams,
      public environment: Environment,
      public googleMaps: GoogleMaps) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SetBackgroundColorPage');
    this.map = this.googleMaps.create('map_canvas');
    this.environment.setBackgroundColor('red');
  }

}
```

Please use this way, mkkekkonen.
I will fix this bug in the next release.

---

**update**

In the next release after @ionic-native@4.3.4, the code would be like this:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-set-background-color',
  templateUrl: 'set-background-color.html'
})
export class SetBackgroundColorPage {

  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor() {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SetBackgroundColorPage');
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas');
    Environment.setBackgroundColor('red');
  }

}
```